# Spark : when will RDD cached in memory?

Tags: apache-spark

```
lines = spark.textFile("hdfs://...")
errors = lines.filter(_.startsWith("ERROR"))
errors.persist()
errors.count()
```

Hi I'm reading the RDD paper and it says RDD won't be put into memory until `count()` is called. And only `errors` will be put into memory, instead of `lines`.

My question is : if `lines` is not in memory, how the `filter()` is done ? Is it done on the HDFS ? In this case isn't it be very slow process ?

Answer (score 0):

Spark will load `lines` and do the `filter` in memory.

Then it will persist the result `errors` (default is in memory).

Comment: So it loads lines in memory or not ? I'm afraid that does not answer the question.

Comment: I had said `in memory`. To be more clearly, `lines` will be in memory until `filter` done

Comment: no, the paper said explicitly lines will not be put in memory. https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/nsdi12/nsdi12-final138.pdf

Comment: It means it will not **persist** in memory.